# prevent protected variable access from child class without using getter and setter in java

Tags: java

Without using getter and setter method  how to prevent modification access from child class if super class has protected Hashmap variable?

This Map is mutable (So i should be able to add the values from super class)So can't use UnmodifiableMap(its only applicable immutable collection object)

```
    Class A
    {
      protected Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      A()
       {
         m.put(10,11)
         m.put(11.12)
       }

      }

    Class B extends A
    {
      B()
      {
        super.m.put(34,90)    —— I don’t want to give access to child       class to add
```

the value and child class and its only should able to get the values.
         }
       }

Comment: Is your goal to create an Immutable map that can be accessed by B to read values? Or is this map going to be modified later?

Comment: if you don't want to modify then make it private final in Super and make use of getter method in Super class so that you can get unmodifiable hashmap.

Comment: B should have only read access for the Map.

Comment: HI Shriram,I know we can use getter and setter but i don't want to use those ,without using how we can prevent.

Answer (score 2):

Make the map unmodifiable, and populate it in the construction of A.

```
class A {
    protected final Map<Integer,Integer> m;

    A() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> tempMap =  = new HashMap<>();
        tempMap.put(10,11);
        tempMap.put(11.12);
        this.m = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap);
    }
}
```

If and when B attempts to modify the map, a ´UnsupportedOperationException´ will be thrown.

If you want A to be able to modify the map, then you'll need a different approach in which the map is private, and a protected getter returns an unmodifiable map.

```
class A {
    private final Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

    A() {
        m.put(10,11);
        m.put(11.12);
        // m remains modifiable within the context of A
    }

    protected Map<Integer, Integer> getMap() {
        return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really don't want to use a getter but still have read-only access, you can use this approach.

```
class A {
    private final Map<Integer,Integer> writableMap = new HashMap<>();
    protected final Map<Integer,Integer> m = Collections.unmodifiableMap(writableMap);

    A() {
        writableMap.put(10,11);
        writableMap.put(11.12);
    }
}
```

Using this approach, only `m` is visible outside A, and is read-only.  Within A, you can update `writableMap` and these changes will be visible in `m`

Comment: HI Steve,if i use unmodifiable map then if i want to add the values in future from super class then i can't do that so unmodifiableMap will not work in this .So i would like my Map to modifiable from Superclass not from Sub class.

Comment: But a childclass would still be able to edit the writable map wouldn't it?  Never mind he has no getter

Comment: No, because writableMap is private.  Child classes can't see it; that's the entire point of  `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of what Steve Chaloner presented in his answer:

```
public class A {

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    protected final Map<Integer,Integer> m = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);

    public A() {
        map.put(10, 11);
        map.put(11, 12);
    }
}
```

The private `map` is modifiable in the `A` class and changes will be reflected in the protected `m` whenever changes are made in `map`.

---

It is being used this way in [Concurrency In Practice](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mzgFCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=java+concurrency+in+practice+unmodifiablemap&source=bl&ots=7V3Lb3_f9Z&sig=652PO-1vlHyLJq6W-3teS6_JiYw&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=xe45VfHkGIWYsgHklYCwBQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=java%20concurrency%20in%20practice%20unmodifiablemap&f=false) for example.

Comment: Is there any other way for this problem?

Comment: @Jena What other way would you need? It solves the problem you have presented to us. Subclasses can **only** access `m` and can **not** do any modifications. Superclass `A` can **still** do modifications.

Comment: HI Maba,Here we end up creating two collection variable  so thats why i am asking for the other way ,its confuse that super class can't use  "m Map" to put the values .

Comment: @Jena Well rename `m` to `readOnlyMap` instead then. I don't really see the problem.

Comment: Thanks Every one for Answering .

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best solution **Composition**:

Implement a new `Map` and keep an internal private modifiable map like this:

```
class A {

    private Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

    protected Map<Integer, Integer> map = new Map<>() {
        //implement interface
        public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public Integer get(Object key) {
            return m.get(key);
        }

        public void clear() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            return m.containsKey(key);
        }

        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            return m.containsValue(value);
        }

        //
        // ... And so on
        //
        // ... with all other methods
    }

    A() {
        m.put(10,11)
        m.put(11.12)
    }


}

class B extends A {
    B() {
       super.map.put(34,90) // thorws exception
       super.m.put(34,90) // inaccesible
    }
}
```

All modifications are allowed in `A` via `m` but subclasses may only acces them by `map` that was succesfully blocked modifications.